# Finding the circle that covers most points in space

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, graph-algorithm

I was at a interview for a High Frequency Trading firm. They asked me for an algorithm of `O(n)`:

- Given `n` points in space
- Given a hash function that returns the points of the plane in `O(1)`,
- Find a best matched circle that covers the most points in space.

### Requirements:

- The circle center has to have integer coordinates and it's radius will be `3`.
- Points within the circle will not necessarily have integer coordinates

I Googled and did some research. There is a **O(n) algorithm (Best circle placement by Chazelle from Princeton University)**, but it is kind of beyond my level to understand and put it together to explain it in 10 mins. I already know `O(n^2)` and `O(n^3)` algorithms.

Please help me find an `O(n)` algorithm.

Answer (score 8):

I guess the integer coordinate constraint simplifies the problem notably. This looks like O(n) to me:

-Make a dictionary of all integer points in space and set the entries to 0.

-For each datapoint find the integer points that are within radius 3, and add 1 to the corresponding entries of the dictionary. The reason for doing this is that the set of points that can be the centers of a circle in which that particular datapoint is inside is the integer restriction of a circle with the same radius around that datapoint. The search could be done over all points lying on a square of length 6 (thought not all points need to be evaluated explicitly as these inside the inscribed hypercube are inside for sure).

-Return the integer point corresponding to the maximum value of the dictionary, ie the center for which most datapoints are inside the circle.

**Edit:** I guess some code is better than explanations. This is working python with numpy and matplotlib. Shouldn't be too difficult to read:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Mar 11 19:22:12 2013

@author: Zah
"""

from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import numpy.random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdict
import timeit
def make_points(n):
    """Generates n random points"""
    return np.random.uniform(0,30,(n,2))

def find_centers(point, r):
    """Given 1 point, find all possible integer centers searching in a square 
    around that point. Note that this method can be imporved."""
    posx, posy = point
    centers = ((x,y) 
        for x in xrange(int(np.ceil(posx - r)), int(np.floor(posx + r)) + 1)
        for y in xrange(int(np.ceil(posy - r)), int(np.floor(posy + r)) + 1)        
        if (x-posx)**2 + (y-posy)**2 < r*r)
    return centers


def find_circle(n, r=3.):
    """Find the best center"""
    points = make_points(n)
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for point in points:
        for center in find_centers(point, r):
            d[center] += 1
    return max(d , key = lambda x: d[x]), points

def make_results():
    """Green circle is the best center. Red crosses are posible centers for some
    random point as an example"""
    r = 3
    center, points = find_circle(100)
    xv,yv = points.transpose()
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_aspect(1)
    ax.scatter(xv,yv)
    ax.add_artist(plt.Circle(center, r, facecolor = 'g', alpha = .5, zorder = 0))
    centersx, centersy  = np.array(list(find_centers(points[0], r))).transpose()
    plt.scatter(centersx, centersy,c = 'r', marker = '+')
    ax.add_artist(plt.Circle(points[0], r, facecolor = 'r', alpha = .25, zorder = 0))
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    make_results()
```

Results:
[image: Result figure]
Green circle is the best one, and the red stuff demonstrates how centers are picked for some random point.

```
In [70]: %timeit find_circle(1000)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.76 s per loop

In [71]: %timeit find_circle(2000)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.51 s per loop

In [72]: %timeit find_circle(3000)
1 loops, best of 3: 5.3 s per loop

In [73]: %timeit find_circle(4000)
1 loops, best of 3: 7.03 s per loop
```

In my really slow machine. Behaviour is clearly linear.

Comment: ya but, in each search, if the circle contains approximately n points, checking n integer center point over n points in dictionary will be O(n^2)

Comment: The cost of a single search does not increase as the number of datapoints (which I understand to be n) increases. Therefore it is O(n).

Comment: -For each datapoint find the integer points that are within radius 3: if I have n-2 points within radius 3(worst case), finding a single point O(1) by hash and finding n points within radius 3 is O(n), now I have to check all the other possible candidate center point for circle in case there is a circle contains n-1 points which is better than a circle that contains n-2 points.

Comment: can you explain me how the cost of a single search does not increase to O(n) ? also points are in 2D space

Comment: But you are not checking for your other datapoints, but for which integer coordinates are inside the circle, and that's a constant number (that grows with the dimensionality but not the number of samples).

Comment: can you please elaborate and give an example. I have a hard time comprehending it. This question is bothering me please.

Comment: This approach will not be O(n). You need to iterate over all O(n) points. But you are introducing O(n^2) additional space to hold the dictionary, and to "return the integer point corresponding to the maximum value of the dictionary" in your last step, you will need to search through all the O(n^2) to find the max-occurring integer point, giving an O(n + n^2) = O(n^2) running time. You could potentially maintain a max-heap to keep track of the max-occurring integer point where you reheapify as you iterate over the O(n) points, so that reduces the time to be O(n lg (n^2)).

Comment: Imagine you have the 1D problem (so the circles are segments) and one million points (n=1e6) distributed from 0 to 10. Then for each point you calculate the integer range [ceil(x-3), floor(x+3)] and add 1 to the corresponding entries. Note that this is independent of the number of points. Then you have to look for the maximum of the dict with a number of entries independent of n. Problem is this does not scale quite well to higher dimensions, but it's O(n) in any case.

Comment: @Zah I still do not see how come "For each datapoint find the integer points that are within radius 3, and add 1 to the corresponding entries of the dictionary" takes O(n), because there might be data points close to n, therefore for each n datapoint you will search n time hence it will take O(n^2)

Comment: Let's try again: given one single point, the set of points at which the center of the circle can be placed so that the point is inside the circle is a circle of radius 3 centered at the point. And you want the integer restriction of that. So you see which of the integer points can have the circle for that point to be inside and add 1 to their corresponding entry. In 2d you have to check 6*6 possible centers per point with  the simplest algorithm I can think of.

Comment: yes I got the now, but now my question getting max from the dictionary will be O(n^2) or even more becase dictionary might contain more than n^2 points depending how the points are located

Comment: Dictionary is size O(n) at worst. Where is that square coming from?

Comment: The dictionary size is not related to n at all. "integer points in space" are grid coordinates, so the dictionary size is determined simply by the range of values.

Comment: @Zah you ought to edit your answer to explain a bit better. This is a good O(n) algorithm but your wording has obviously caused some confusion.

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand what was so confusing. Anyway, hope it's better now.

Comment: nice+1.. its one of those thing that makes perfect sense only after you understand it..

Answer (score 4):

There is a different idea than stated in (1) which reduces the number of circles to be examined to `O(n)`

**key discovery:**
- For one data point p, there is should be only a limited number of circles with radius 3 which can include the data point p!
In other words: the number of circles which have (1st) radius 3 (2nd) integers as center point coordinates and (3rd) which do include one specific data point is  O(1)!

**Key idea:**
Iterate over all potential circles with radius 3, and count for each circle the number of data points it would include.

**Algorithm:**
- We initialize an empty hashtable h which maps a circle centerpoint  - i.e. a combination of (i,j) where both i and j are integers - to a integer number

```
- For data point p_i in p_1 ... p_n // this loop takes O(n)
    - determine all the centerpoints c_1, c_2 ... c_k of circles which 
      can include p_i (in O(1))
    - for each centerpoint c_j in c_1... c_k // this loop takes O(1)
       - lookup if there is an entry hashtable i.e. test h[c_j]==nil
       - if h[c_j]==nil then h[c_j]:=1 end
       - else h[c_j] := h[c_j] +1 end
    - end for 
 end for
```

// this last maximum determination takes O(n)
 - Iterate over all c_k in h
 - determine key c_max where  h_[c_max] is the maximim value in h

What do you think?
Any comments are welcome.